# How to deal with repetitive parameters?

Tags: php, laravel, software-design

How to deal many repetitive parameters in a `create()`. I like to look tidy and and readable.

For example in the controller, we have `addList`() method with many parameters.

```
public function addList(CreateListRequest $request)
{
    $created = $this->list->create(
                  $request->user(),             
                  $request->name,
                  $request->subject,
                  $request->description, 
                  $request->location,
                  $request->do_email,
                  $request->provider,
                  $request->something1,
                  $request->something2, 
                );
}
```

In the `List` class we have a create methods which also many repetitive many parameters. And in the `$this->api->create()` and `$this->listRepository->create()` which is also kinda repeated. Is there a way to clean this up or refactor this?

```
class List
{
    public function create($user, $name, $subject, $description, $location, $doEmail, $provider, $something, $something2)
    {
       $list = $this->api->create($name, $subject, $description, $location);

       if ($list->status == "success") {
            // Add to database
           $row = $this->listRepository->create($user->id, $name, $subject, $description, $location, $doEmail, $provider, $something, $something2);
          return $row;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems to me the only parameter the `create()` method needs, is the `$request` variable. Is the `create()` method used by other objects and do they all share the same signature?

Comment: I'd consider posting this to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Would a `ListForm` class fit into your structure? In Symfony you create form classes, pass it the request and it will populate the form data based on the request, could be extended to do validations etc as well. If so you could do something like this in addList: `$form = new ListForm(); $form->handleRequest($request); $created = $this->list->create($form);` And then List::create could be `create(ListForm $form)` which will give auto completion etc.

Comment: @JimL Like create an entity object?

Comment: Encapsulate, Abstract and Separate Responsibility. Simply use a Factory `ListFactory::fromRequest(Request $request);` `new List($id, $name, ...$arguments);` That way wherever you will need to build a list from a `Request` you way use your factory to do it and have only *ONE* place to make changes if you add / remove new parameters to your constructor. You `ListFactory` can also provide other method to build your object (`::fromJson()`, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Passing request object is good rather than sending the every 
parameter individually.

```
public function addList(CreateListRequest $request) {
    $created = $this->list->create($request);
}
```

In List class, since request object anyways has user session, 
simply pass the request object to listRepository class.

```
class List {

    public function create($request) {

        $list = $this->api->create($request->only(['name', 'subject', 'description', 'location']));

        if ($list->status == "success") {
            $row = $this->listRepository->create($request);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What if you want to create without request via browser?

Comment: I don't get you. Do you mean through API?

Comment: I mean I might want to call `list->create()` not via browser. Let say via console or other class that has nothing to do with http request.

Comment: I do seriously not advise to tie the `Request` dependency to the `List` object.

Comment: Yes. Totally agreed, with the new helper in laravel, you could remove $request parameter and then access the request object using the "request()" function